# Как выделить слово в тексте c++ winapi

Tags: c++, winapi

Я хочу написать что-то на подобие редактора кода с подсветкой, но вот как реализовать эту самую подсветку кода не знаю. Анализатор текста имеется, нужно просто написать определённое слово другим цветом.

P.S. без сторонних библиотек (только winapi c/c++)

Comment: Вам придётся писать анализатор исходного текста, который желаете подсвечивать, с целью распознать отдельные токены, такие как имена переменных, числа, строки, ключевые слова и т.п. Минимум базовых знаний для этого можете почерпнуть из книги Альфреда Ахо "Компиляторы. Принципы, технологии и инструментарий".

Comment: @LShadow77 спасибо вам! Но с токенами и т.п. я уже давно разобрался, осталась только подсветка.

Comment: как вариант, преобразуете текст в массив токенов. В каждый токен, помимо типа лексемы, помещаете указатель на начало токена в тексте, количество символов, а также координаты (x,y) относительно "листа" с текстом, которые рассчитываете исходя из метрик шрифта. Ну а в момент отрисовки просто выводите содержимое этих токенов с помощью `TextOut()`, каждый токен своим цветом. А вообще текст удобнее представить в виде массива (`std::vector`) или списка (`std::list`) структур-строк, каждая из которых, в свою очередь, содержит массив/список токенов. Как-то так.